# React/MUI: Issue Implementing Dark/Light Theme Toggle with Context API - Theme not Toggling Properly

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, themes

I am currently working on a React project that utilizes Material-UI for the UI components. I am attempting to implement a simple **dark/light theme toggle** using the Context API provided by React. However, I have encountered an issue where the **theme is not toggling properly, and the UI is not reflecting the theme changes as expected**.

CodeSandBox for the issue - [Check it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-light-mode-96mlcs?file=/src/App.js)

Below is the simplified code structure for the theme provider, the component where the theme toggle functionality is implemented and the userLocalStorage script which saves the user's theme preference (light or dark).

**Component handling the theme toggling**

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { CssBaseline, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { blue, indigo } from '@mui/material/colors';
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import useLocalStorage from '../../hooks/localstorage/useLocalStorage';

const AppThemeContext = createContext({
    theme: "light",
    toggleTheme: () => {
    }
});

const themes = {
    light: createTheme({
        palette: {
            mode: "light",
            primary: indigo,
            secondary: blue,
        },
    }),
    dark: createTheme({
        palette: {
            mode: "dark",
            primary: indigo,
            secondary: blue,
        },
    }),
};

const themeKey = "loop_app_theme"

const AppThemeProvider = (props) => {
    const userPreferredTheme = useLocalStorage({ fallback: "light", key: themeKey })
    
    const toggleTheme = useCallback(() => {
        if (userPreferredTheme.value === "light") {
            userPreferredTheme.setItem(themeKey, "dark");
            return;
        }
        userPreferredTheme.setItem(themeKey, "light");
    }, [userPreferredTheme])
    return (
        <AppThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme: userPreferredTheme.value, toggleTheme }}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={themes[userPreferredTheme.value]}>
                <CssBaseline />
                {props.children}
            </ThemeProvider>
        </AppThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAppTheme = () => useContext(AppThemeContext);

export default AppThemeProvider
```

**userLocalStorage.js:** (Saves the theme based on user's preference)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useLocalStorage = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.fallback);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props?.override) {
      localStorage.setItem(props.key, value);
    } else {
      const localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem(props.key);
      if (localStorageItem) {
        setValue(localStorageItem);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(props.key, props.fallback);
      }
    }
  }, [props.key, props.fallback, props.override, value]);
  const setItem = (key, value) => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    setValue(value);
  };
  return { value, setItem };
};

export default useLocalStorage;

useLocalStorage.defaultProps = {
  fallback: "storage default value",
};
```

**Child Component using the feature (frontend)**

```
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader, Stack, Switch, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAppTheme } from '../../../../../providers/Theme';
import MetaDataProvider from '../../../../../providers/Meta';
import { BRAND_NAME } from '../../../../../constants';

const SettingsPreferencesPage = () => {
  const themeCtx = useAppTheme();
  
  const [isDarkModeEnabled, setIsDarkModeEnabled] = useState(themeCtx.theme === "dark");

  const handleToggleTheme = () => {
    console.log(themeCtx.theme);
    setIsDarkModeEnabled(!isDarkModeEnabled);
    themeCtx.toggleTheme();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MetaDataProvider title={`${BRAND_NAME} | Settings | Preferences`} />
      <Stack>
        <Typography variant="h6" fontWeight={400}>
          Your Preferences
        </Typography>
        <Card>
          <CardHeader subheader="Toggle your theme to light/dark" title="Theme" />
          <CardContent>
            <Switch checked={isDarkModeEnabled} onChange={handleToggleTheme} title="mode" />
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
};

export default SettingsPreferencesPage;
```

Could someone please review the code and suggest potential solutions to ensure that the theme toggle functionality works as intended?

Comment: Please share a CodeSandbox that reproduces your code with the problem you're facing. Have you reviewed ["Toggling color modes"](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#toggling-color-mode) in the Material UI Dark Mode doc? The implementation there is solid.

Comment: @SamSycamore I have created a CodeSandbox for this issue, you can go through it. I did go through the docs, but could not find any possible issue in my code.